# How to open terminal from the macOS terminal?

Tags: terminal, command-line, applications, bash, karabiner

On the macOS terminal it is possible to open applications with the shell command below:

```bash
open '/Applications/Brave Browser.app'
```

I use this shell command bound to my hotkeys in order to open an application (if not already opened) **and also** to move the focus to Brave browser. Hence, in my [karabiner-elements](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/) `.config` file I have:

```json
{
    "description": "left_command + b -> Brave",
    "manipulators": [
        {
            "from": {
                "key_code": "b",
                "modifiers": {
                    "mandatory": [
                        "left_command"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "to": [
                {
                    "shell_command": "open '/Applications/Brave Browser.app'"
                }
            ],
            "type": "basic"
        }
    ]
}
```

I also have something similar for Emacs:

```json
{
    "description": "left_command + e -> Emacs",
    "manipulators": [
        {
            "from": {
                "key_code": "e",
                "modifiers": {
                    "mandatory": [
                        "left_command"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "to": [
                {
                    "shell_command": "open -a emacs"
                }
            ],
            "type": "basic"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is very handy on window management. I would like to do the same, but with the terminal!

How can I do the same with the terminal application itself? **What is the shell command to open the terminal from the terminal**?

Following a suggestion on Stack Overflow, I tried the approach below, but it **did not** work out:

```json
{
    "description": "left_command + k -> focus on terminal",
    "manipulators": [
        {
            "from": {
                "key_code": "b",
                "modifiers": {
                    "mandatory": [
                        "left_command"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "to": [
                {
                    "shell_command": "osascript -e 'tell application \"Terminal\" to activate' \
          -e 'tell app \"System Events\" to keystroke \"n\" using command down'"
                }
            ],
            "type": "basic"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can‘t you just press Cmd-T to create a new tab?

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, @nohillside. But, no. Cmd-t will not help me. For instance, it would not help with the hotkey for window management.

Comment: Whats wrong with simple `open -n '/System/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app'`?

Comment: Thank you, @AivarPaalberg. This is what I was looking for. It was *almost* exactly what I want. I just tweaked the flag from `-n` to `-a`.

Comment: I did not realize the Terminal was actually an Application.

Answer (score 3):

If the system is allowed to (somewhere under the Privacy/Accessibility preferences) a script could be run that would bring the terminal to the forground and open a new window,

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to activate' \
          -e 'tell app "System Events" to keystroke "n" using command down'
```

or use `"t"` instead of `"n"` if you want tabs instead of new windows. Also the code may need to account for the terminal already being open, or not. It may run faster if compiled into a *programfile*  with the Script Editor.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. I tried your approach, but it did not work out. I have just updated my question including my attempt of your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

@AivarPaalberg helped me figure this out by commenting on the post. Thus, I am posting an answer. There is just a minor adjustment by changing the `open` flag from `-n` to `-a`:

```json
{
    "description": "left_command + k -> terminal",
    "manipulators": [
        {
            "from": {
                "key_code": "k",
                "modifiers": {
                    "mandatory": [
                        "left_command"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "to": [
                {
                    "shell_command": "open -a '/System/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app'"
                }
            ],
            "type": "basic"
        }
    ]
}
```

If flag `-a` was used and Terminal was already open, then there would be an annoying message such as the one below:

[image]

Comment: Documentation says that about `-n` flag: "Open a new instance of the application(s) even if one is already running." and about `-a` flag: "Specifies the application to use for opening the file". Do you want to open new instance of the terminal or do you want to open the file?

Comment: You don’t need to specify paths to applications with the `open` command.  Simply `open -a Terminal` will do, or if you want a new instance: `open -n -a Terminal`.